# What plugin it is better to use for build swing interface using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

What plugin it is better to use for build swing interface using Eclipse?

Comment: No GUI builder is a substitute for understanding how layouts work.

Comment: He didn't ask to be mentored in GUI layouts, maybe this is a 1 hour throw away project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows Builder Pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html) from Instantiations (now owned by Google)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Swing GUI Designer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/swing-gui-designer)