# Swing GUI Control Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-plugin

I developed a small application in Java using Eclipse IDE. Now i want to make UI for that application. Since i don't have much command over JAVA so i am looking for some drag and drop feature. I heard that netbeans provide the drag and drop functionality, but ideally i am looking for some Eclipse plug-in that provides SWING control. Please share if any such plugin exists.

Comment: gosh, if only this had been asked before...

Comment: possible duplicate of [what eclipse GUI builder plugin do you suggest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942696/what-eclipse-gui-builder-plugin-do-you-suggest)

Comment: and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064204/what-plugin-it-is-better-to-use-for-build-swing-interface-using-eclipse

Comment: and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694614/what-is-the-preferred-visual-editor-eclipse-plugin-for-swing-apps-in-2011.  Original poster -- didn't you search before asking this?

Comment: Just as a radial arm saw is not the same as carpentry, a GUI editor is an aid to craftsmanship, not a substitute for understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and free one IMO is **WindowBuilder Pro** from Google.

More info is at http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html

Comment: Didn't you answer this very same question recently before? Shouldn't this question be closed as a duplicate of a gazillion similar questions?

Comment: I did :) but I have no problem answering again. It is not a difficult or long answer :)

Comment: Please review/correct this recently edited [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942696/what-eclipse-gui-builder-plugin-do-you-suggest/942875#942875).